# ЯСТИ  и  ЕДА

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Считаются ли однокоренными эти два русских слова:
ЯСТИ  и  ЕДА ?

Comment: Да, это однокоренные слова, поскольку в ЯСТИ на первом месте была буква ять, открытое е.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Русского* слова "ясти" сейчас не существует. Будьте уж точны, если вы *проф.языковед*.

Answer (score 3):

В др.-рус. языке с 11 века: ѣсти, ѣдати, ѣдо (еда), и.-е. корень еd - есть.

Чередование СТ/Д  вообще характерно для русского языка: вести - ведет.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера!
Я ведь почему спросил. Оказывается, не только у нас ЕДА и ЕСТЬ (КУШАТЬ) - однокоренные, но и в других языках: 
Например,  в английском ЕСТЬ -EAT, а ЕДА -EATING.
Хотя, в греческом при наличии однокоренного с нашим слова ΕΔΩΔΙΜΑ (ЕДОДИМА) - продовольствие, слово ЕШЬ (КУШАЙ) имеет уже другой корень ΦΆΩ (FÁO̱ )
 
Скажите, а звук  ѣ (ѣсти) в древнерусском в начале слова мог произноситься, как нынешний наш Я?

Comment: Федя, у меня есть интересная книга Т. Мироновой "Путешествие в Древнюю Русь" и Грамматика древнерусского языка для детей", но ее и взрослым читать очень интересно. Дети попадают в Древнюю Русь и пытаются приспособиться к той жизни и даже научиться говорить. А в краткой грамматике даются сведения по языку на уровне, достаточном для его начального понимания (потом уже можно при желании обратиться к более серьезной литературе).

Comment: Вот что сказано в этой книге про букву "ять". Звук, обозначаемый буквой "ять", существовал в др.-рус. языке, но он утрачивается начиная с 13 века. В некоторых говорах (например, в Новгороде) этот звук произносился как ИЕ. На месте этого звука теперь находится  Э, но мы и сейчас можем узнать, в каких словах он когда-то звучал. Это большинство слов, в которых перед обычно твердым согласным слышится ударный гласный Е: лес, хлеб, сено. А там, где был исконный Э, произошло чередование Е/Ё: медъ - мёд.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это однокоренные слова, поскольку в ЯСТИ на первом месте была буква ять, открытое е.
Большинство иных употреблений этого звука в древнерусском языке при реформе 1918 года отождествили с Е, а в этом древнем варианте слова ЕСТЬ приняли Я.